# Where to keep related patient information in fhir

Tags: dstu2-fhir, hl7-fhir

I am trying to convert a patient to fhir compliant patient. One of the attributes in our patient structure is 'related patient'. This attribute lists down all other patients who are related to the given patient.

Example , patient p1 is a father of patient p2. So, p1 has a attribute 'related patients' and the value of that attribute is a list containing p2.

Where should I keep this 'related patient' information in fhir object model ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The FamilyMemberHistory resource has an extension (http://www.hl7.org/fhir/extension-familymemberhistory-patient-record.html) that lets you link that particular family member to the corresponding Patient record for that person.  At the moment, there's no way to do that directly from Patient, though you could define an extension that would do that if you really needed to.

Comment: Thanks for the response. This helped.